# data reader in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datareader

Please help, how do I make a while loop  equivalent of this for loop. So that I could read from one row in the table of mysql database and display  it on the combobox in vb.net.

I use this code, but its definitely not useful if there are 3 or more items that are added in the row:

```
Dim i As Integer
        Dim rdr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
        rdr = con.readfrom_drug_type_table()
    For i = 0 To 1
        If rdr.HasRows = True Then
            rdr.Read()

            ComboBox2.Items.Add(rdr("Drug_type"))
        End If
    Next i
```

I want to read all the data from that the Drug_type row
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read only first row than just use

```
If rdr.Read() Then 
     ComboBox2.Items.Add(rdr("Drug_type")) 
End If
```

Update

```
Try
    myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=pubs")
    'you need to provide password for sql server
    myConnection.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from discounts", myConnection)
    dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            WriteLine(dr(0))
            WriteLine(dr(1))
            WriteLine(dr(2))
            WriteLine(dr(3))
            WriteLine(dr(4))
            ' writing to console
        End While
Catch
End Try
dr.Close()
myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, it seems that you only copied and pasted it from somewhere else. As you can see I'm using odbc to connect to mysql database. I'm not using mysql connector.net

Comment: yeah to show you its very easy you can also find by googling antoher fact is i am for c# backgroud so cannt provice you code in vb.net

Answer (score 2):

@pranay
You don't need the nested loops.

```
Try
    myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=pubs")
    myConnection.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from discounts", myConnection)
    dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        WriteLine(dr(0))
        WriteLine(dr(1))
        WriteLine(dr(2))
        WriteLine(dr(3))
        WriteLine(dr(4))
    End While
    dr.Close()
Finally
    myConnection.Close()
End Try
```